# HashMap with std::future as the key

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, future

Since we cannot get the arguments from `std::future`, I am trying to maintain a map between `std::future` and `std::string`. The following statement:

`std::unordered_map<std::future<void>, std::string> map` fails with the following error:

```
error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<std::future<void> >) (const std::future<void>&)'                                   │      =•
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You solve it by providing a hash function for `std::future<void>` and a way to compare them for equality. But this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160609).

Comment: Use `future<string>` (or `future<SomethingThatContainsNecessaryContext>`) instead. Wrap the actual task functor in one that takes a string, calls the functor, and returns the string back.

Comment: If you think this is an XY problem, here is what I am trying to solve.
I have several long running sub tasks. I have each of them running as `std::async<std::launch::async, LongRunningTask, arg1, arg2>`.

I have it all pushed to a `std::vector`.  After completing several other operation, I need to wait for all the tasks to finish. As a part of it, I need to log a message which says on which task I am waiting for currently.

`while(!vector.empty()) {
  // Log the arguments of the future. THIS IS THE PROBLEM.
  vector.back().get();
  vector.pop_back();
}
`
@Praetorian

Comment: Have a vector of `std::pair<future<void>, string>` instead. Compose the string at the same time you prepare the async task, and add both to the vector together.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense with your clarification. Futures as keys doesn't make sense, they are not comparable or even copyable, how would you attempt to access anything in that map?

Comment: Do what Igor suggests, or generalize it to `vector<MyContextType>`, where `MyContextType` contains `future<void>` and `string` data members, and possibly other things you may want to store.

Comment: Also, futures are mutable by definition: they change after you access the valid and the validity of them is changed. Don't try to hash mutable values. There's no API to access a raw pointer or state of the future that is immutable, so....

Comment: So it looks to me that you already have the futures themselves held in a list of pending tasks, and you just need a diagnostic hash to tell you the arguments that launched a particular task? If so your hash index should be the address of the future, not the actual future itself?